# SQL Recursive query on Parent > Child Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, recursive-query

I’ve been asked to do various exports directly from a bespoke database I have no control over.

One small part is a set of parent child relationships stored rather badly. They don’t have any sort of individual unique id either.

Now I can export this to another database in a different format or even do it in code. (I probably will do this).

I’m curious if I can do this directly with just simply SQL recursively without temp tables etc (or specific version this is MS SQL Server).

The table is as follows:

[image: Table]

Null meaning no parent.

Each id relates to a different table but that isn’t important.

What I’m trying to extrapolate is the “path” (first column of the following) of each relationship as follows.

[image]

1-5-6 could be something like Country-State-Town. It isn’t, or is it important but just an idea of what these ids may represent.

I know the actual paths because of other hard-coded parts of the system.

There are issues with this design, but I suspect some are avoided as of hard coding some of the design.

Comment: "
marked as duplicate by Zohar Peled sql 17 mins ago

This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."  How does this answer the question. Did you even bother to read mine. This doesnt answer the question at all nor is it related. The table on the "duplicate" question isnt even the same. I do get bored with badge collectors. Its why most folk dont even bother with stack overflow anymore.

Comment: If you can show me how that answers my question then Im all ears. If not then you are simply one of the badge collectors...